# Disable per test "dots" while pytest-ing

Tags: python, terminal, pytest

I have parametrized test suite with ~10^5 tests. And I'm debugging raised errors consequently, I.e using `-x` flag. Like so:

```
pytest tests.py -x
```

Problem here is that this command cluttering terminal with `.` corresponding to each test. Which is not desired (cause I have no any xfaild or something - only passed or not; and due to the number of tests):

```
............................................................................................................................................................................................................ [  5%]
............................................................................................................................................................................................................ [ 11%]
............................................................................................................................................................................................................ [ 17%]
```

How to disable this "dots" and left only progress bar? Maybe some plugin? Tried `-q` but dots still printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement the [`pytest_report_teststatus()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_report_teststatus) hook in your `conftest.py`. It returns a tuple result-category, shortletter and verbose word.

```
def pytest_report_teststatus(report, config):
    if report.passed and report.when == "call":
        return report.outcome, "", report.outcome.upper()
```

The hook is called 3 times for each test, with `report.when` set to `"setup"`, `"call"` or `"teardown"`. The callback above sets the shortletter to an empty string if the test passes in the `"call"` phase.

Comment: In general it works. But 2 remarks here: if one have plugins installed that modifies output like `pytest-sugar` it must be disabled in order this approach works - `-p no:sugar`. And  second one - this hook also "disables" a progress bar which is not desired but this might be tweaked to work I suppose.